# WooCommerce statewise shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

We have a WooCommerce setup, we need multiple state pricing for eg. Maharashtra and Out of Maharashtra (OMS).

So the challenge is that we need to ask customer about his *State* once he enters in the website and then upto his selection the price of all the products are `x` in Maharashtra and `x+10` in OMS.

Looking for some help on how to proceed with it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the explanation, you want to add an additional cost of Rs.10 for all orders outside Maharastra. Correct me if I am wrong.

You will be able to achieve it using this code snippet.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','my_custom_surcharge' );
function my_custom_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    $state      = array('MH');
    $surcharge  = 10;
    if ( in_array( WC()->customer->shipping_state, $state ) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Additional Charge', $surcharge, true, '' );
    }
}
```

Details on this snippet is referred from [this article](http://www.xadapter.com/2016/05/31/woocommerce-add-an-additional-fee-based-on-state/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Really sorry for not being clear, we need each products price to increase by INR 10 if OMS.. So if Maharashtra (product cost is x), if OMS (product cost is x +10)

Comment: Hey Guys 

Anyone there with a solution??